# javascript using select box to fill other select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I am trying to create a Make, Model, and Year select drop down similar to many car sites such as Autotrader. However I am having difficulty getting the second select drop down to populate after the user first selects the initial drop down. Hoping for suggestions.

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="make" class="form-control">
        <option>Make</option>
        <option>Chevrolet</option>
        <option>Ford</option>
        <option>GMC</option>
        <option>Toyota</option> 
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 mob">
        <select id="models" class="form-control models" disabled>
            <option>Model</option>
            <option>Silverado</option>
            <option>Suburban</option>
            <option>Tahoe</option>
        </select>               
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
//setup arrays
Chevrolet = ['Silverado','Suburban','Tahoe'];
Ford = ['F150','Taurus','Pinto','Bronco'];
Toyota = ['Camry','Tacoma','4Runner'];
GMC = ['blah1','blah2','blah3'];

$('#make').change(function() {
    $('#models').prop('disabled', true);
    $("#models").html(""); //clear existing options

    var newOptions = window[this.value]; //finds the array w/the name of the selected value
    //populate the new options
    for (var i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
        $("#models").append("<option>"+newOptions[i]+"</option>");
    }

    $('#models').prop('disabled', false); //enable the dropdown
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/W9TLT/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't include the jquery library - incuding it works for me

Comment: See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9TLT/2/) with jquery included.

Comment: On a side note, it would be faster to use `$("#models").empty();` than `$("#models").html("");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include jquery in your fiddle.

That said, you shouldn't really use a global, instead make your own object and modify your code slightly:

```
$(function(){    
    //setup arrays
    var cars = {
        "Chevrolet" : ['Silverado','Suburban','Tahoe'],
        "Ford" : ['F150','Taurus','Pinto','Bronco'],
        "Toyota" : ['Camry','Tacoma','4Runner'],
        "GMC" : ['blah1','blah2','blah3']
    };

    $('#make').change(function() {
        $("#models").html(""); //clear existing options
        var newOptions = cars[this.value]; //finds the array w/the name of the selected value
        //populate the new options
        for (var i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
            $("#models").append("<option>"+newOptions[i]+"</option>");
        }
        $('#models').prop('disabled', false); //enable the dropdown
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W9TLT/10/

Another note.  Disabling the dropdown at the start of your code and then enabling it at the end has no effect other than to enable the dropdown.  Due to the single-threaded nature of browsers/javascript, the disable never really happens.  All that matters is what it is set to when the code completes.

Comment: James, I have added the code to my site yet still cannot get the javascript to function. Would you mind taking a look? http://buddytruk.com/driver/

Comment: You put the code inside of a function which you call onclick.  You shouldn't do that.  It should be outside of the function.  It should run when the page is initially parsed.

Comment: Yes, I changed that. Not sure why that was there. It is still not running correctly.

Comment: Seems like you're using something to make your select boxes pretty that isn't triggering the change event.

Comment: Actually, that may not be true.  Your "city" dropdown has an `id` of "make".  `id` values can't be duplicated.

Comment: It was the id in 'city'. Thanks man for going above and beyond. Most people wouldn't waste their time debugging someone else's project. You are a good man.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle doesn't have jQuery loaded!

```
$('#make').change(function() {
    $('#models').prop('disabled', true);
    $("#models").html(""); //clear existing options
    var newOptions = window[this.value]; //finds the array w/the name of the selected value
    //populate the new options
    for (var i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
        $("#models").append("<option>"+newOptions[i]+"</option>");
    }
    $('#models').prop('disabled', false); //enable the dropdown
});
```

[Working](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/W9TLT/3/)

Comment: I have added the code to my site yet still cannot get the javascript to function. Would you mind taking a look? http://buddytruk.com/driver/

Comment: Load all your scripts inside `<head>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery. Your example works.