# Javascript Selectbox to fill other selectbox regarding option order

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 selectboxes. What I want to do is autoselect the second selectbox by selecting a value from selectbox1. I can auto populate the values but what I need here is to select `option` by order regardless of `value`.

If I select `option1` on selectbox1 with `value=A`, then it should select `option1` on selectbox2 with `value="1"` according to below

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">First Select</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <select  name="firstSELECT" class="select validate[required]">
         <option value="A" class="opm">12345</option>
         <option value="B" class="opm">23456</option>
         <option value="C" class="opm">34567</option>
         <option value="D" class="opm">45678</option>
         <option value="E" class="opm">56789</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <label class="control-label">Second Select</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <select  name="secondSELECT" class="select validate[required]">
         <option value="1" class="opm">ABCDE</option>
         <option value="2" class="opm">BCDEF</option>
         <option value="3" class="opm">CDEFG</option>
         <option value="4" class="opm">DEFGH</option>
         <option value="5" class="opm">EFGHI</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried a method like [javascript using select box to fill other select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466607/javascript-using-select-box-to-fill-other-select-box) but since I need to select according the order of option, not value; I wasn't able to do it since I am very new with Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it necessary to select according to the option instead of the value? From what I can see from your example it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @DKyleo Actually only order matters for me in this situation. For instance, if I select `option4` from `selectbox1`, it should autmatically select `option4` in `selectbox2` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```js
function update() {
    var firstSelect = document.getElementsByName("firstSELECT")[0];
    var secondSelect = document.getElementsByName("secondSELECT")[0];
    
    var optN;
    
    for (i=0;i<firstSelect.children.length;i++) {
        if (firstSelect.children[i].selected) {
            secondSelect.children[i].selected = "1";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">First Select</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <select  name="firstSELECT" class="select validate[required]" oninput="update()">
         <option value="A" class="opm">12345</option>
         <option value="B" class="opm">23456</option>
         <option value="C" class="opm">34567</option>
         <option value="D" class="opm">45678</option>
         <option value="E" class="opm">56789</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <label class="control-label">Second Select</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <select  name="secondSELECT" class="select validate[required]">
         <option value="1" class="opm">ABCDE</option>
         <option value="2" class="opm">BCDEF</option>
         <option value="3" class="opm">CDEFG</option>
         <option value="4" class="opm">DEFGH</option>
         <option value="5" class="opm">EFGHI</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

We loop trough all the `<option>` elements in the first `<select>`, and when we find the selected, we select the `<option>` with the same index in the second `<select>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">First Select</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <select  name="firstSELECT" id="a" class="select validate[required]" onchange="document.getElementById('b').value=document.getElementById('a').value">
         <option value="A" class="opm">12345</option>
         <option value="B" class="opm">23456</option>
         <option value="C" class="opm">34567</option>
         <option value="D" class="opm">45678</option>
         <option value="E" class="opm">56789</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <label class="control-label">Second Select</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <select  name="secondSELECT" id="b" class="select validate[required]">
         <option value="A" class="opm">ABCDE</option>
         <option value="B" class="opm">BCDEF</option>
         <option value="C" class="opm">CDEFG</option>
         <option value="D" class="opm">DEFGH</option>
         <option value="E" class="opm">EFGHI</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @fzs, thanks for the solution but the thing is my `value`'s are different in each selectbox

Answer (score 1):

Here's the jQuery way of doing it:

```js
$(".selectFirst").change(function(e) {
  var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
  var idx = $(this).children().index(selectedOption)
  var secChildIdx = $(".selectSecond").children()[idx];
  $(".selectSecond").find(":selected").removeAttr('selected');
  $(secChildIdx).attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">First Select</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select name="firstSELECT" class="selectFirst select validate[required]">
      <option value="A" class="opm">12345</option>
      <option value="B" class="opm">23456</option>
      <option value="C" class="opm">34567</option>
      <option value="D" class="opm">45678</option>
      <option value="E" class="opm">56789</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label class="control-label">Second Select</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select name="secondSELECT" class="selectSecond select validate[required]">
      <option value="1" class="opm">ABCDE</option>
      <option value="2" class="opm">BCDEF</option>
      <option value="3" class="opm">CDEFG</option>
      <option value="4" class="opm">DEFGH</option>
      <option value="5" class="opm">EFGHI</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pelin well this works with jQuery library, are you familiar with it? Or do you want to code in plain (vanilla) JavaScript?

Comment: I ment on code snippet, I tested it A to E it worked fine, then I tested a few more but it stopped working

Comment: Yes I gather that. It was my silly mistake. I've corrected the code. Hope it's working fine now.

Comment: @Pelin could you try running it on your local system? It works well on my local system but doesn't work on StackOverflow. Please check :)

Comment: Thank you for responses but unfortunately same in local too, after a few tries it stopped working :(

Comment: @Pelin I think I found what was wrong. The lastest version of jQuery available on StackOverflow was 2.2 I've updated it to 3.3 I think it shall work now.

Comment: Hey, yup its working now. But I am using jquery 2.3, so having an issue gotta use your approach if I manage to get it work with older version :) Thank you!

Comment: Best of luck @Pelin